# Change target framework from .NET Core to .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have created a project in Visual Studio 2019 as C# .NET Core windows forms app. But report viewer is not available in .net core version of applications. So I want to keep my project same but want to change the framework from **.NET CORE** to **.NET Framework.** Please help sir.

i have tried each and every step to do this but unable to do this

Comment: So, what the real problem here? Just set the `<TargetFramework>net48-windows</TargetFramework>` in the csproj.

Comment: Have you considered the [ReportViewerCore.NETCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewerCore.NETCore/) NuGet package?

Comment: I don’t know how to use that andrew. Because theres no youtube video available for [ ReportViewerCore.NETCore ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the question is only about `TF`, then just change it in project file:

```
<TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
```